# Как из массива вывести положительные числа в порядке убывания

Tags: c#, массивы, пузырьковая-сортировка

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ввод чисел
        int temp;
        int s = -1;
        int N;
        Console.Write("Введите количество элементов массива: ");
        N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] A = new int[N];


        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите " + (i + 1) + " число: ");
            A[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        foreach (int F in A)
            if (F > 0);
        for (int j = 0; j < A.Length; j++)// сортировка
            for (int i = 0; i < A.Length - 1; i++)
            {

                if (A[i] * s > A[i + 1] * s)
                {
                    temp = A[i];
                    A[i] = A[i + 1];
                    A[i + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(A[i] + "\t"); // вывод массива
        }                                   //положительные




        foreach (int D in A)
            Console.Write(Math.Abs(D)+ "\t");//отрицательные
    }
}
```

В общем, задача состоялась в том, чтобы вывести из массива отрицательные числа в порядке возрастания по модулю, а положительные в порядке убывания. Помогите пожалуйста, уже не знаю что делать.
Допустим ввел я: 10, -20, -30, 40;
А получить должен:
(40 10) 
и
(20 30)

Comment: отсортируйте массив по возрастанию. далее 2 цикла. первый с конца к началу, отрицательные пропускаете, положительные выводите. Второй - от начала к концу, положительные пропускаете, модуль выводите

Comment: зы:вторую итерацию сортировки от `j+1` начинайте, а не от нуля.

Comment: @teran возрастание модуля отрицательных чисел совпадает с убыванием положительных, так что тут оба цикла для вывода в одну сторону, можно даже заменить одним при желании.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае задачу можно разбить на 2 задачи. Разбейте один массив на 2 массива, один с положительными числами, другой с отрицательными. Преобразуйте/отсортируйте как надо, а потом соберите обратно в один массив. Ваш код будет очень понятным и компилятор сможет его намного лучше оптимизировать.

В коде, особенно на C#, это выглядит очень лаконично с использование Linq. Собственно, настолько компактно, что можно написать прямо здесь:

```
var secondPart = sourceCollection.Where(x => x < 0).Select(x => x * -1).OrderBy(x => x);
var firstPart = sourceCollection.Where(x => x >= 0).OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
firstPart.AddRange(secondPart);

var result = firstPart;
```

Если для вас это сложновато, то сделайте это обычными циклами.